# powermail does not send

Tags: php, hosting, typo3-7.6.x, powermail

I am using typo3 7.6.14 and powermail 3.10.0 with default configuration. First i just installed the extension as described in the docs. In Frontend after submitting the form the page is reloaded but nothing else happens.

I have to say that i am working on host europe server at the moment (php 5.6.29). On my local machine same code works (php 5.5.27). the form is submitted and a short message is given to the user. but on live server nothing ... On live server "send test mail" via install tool works.

Maybe it is a general problem about hosting. Any ideas?

Comment: On a completely different note, if you use TYPO3 7.6, you can switch to php 7. Also, here's an (old) post about debugging approaches (in german) https://www.web-vision.de/support/Knowledgebase/Article/View/480/5/powermail-209-sendet-keine-emails-unter-typo3-613 for powermail send issues.

Comment: First thing I'd check is if the email is stored in the database, and what is stored

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that i had to register an valid email at hosteurope example@my-domain.com. This email i had to register in typo3 install tool->all configuration ->defaultMailFromAddress. And of course in powermail frontend plugin. At least submitting the form is now working. Submitted data can now be seen in typo3 backend. What is not working is the message to the admin that a mail request was made.